# Testing on iPhone Simulator w/o License

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos, programming-languages

I have a few questions to ask. Currently, I'm self-learning iphone programming, and later maybe for mac. I just need to make sure my apps works accordingly.

So do I need a license to test on the iphone simulator? I don't need to test on a real device. I don't intend to put anything up on apps store in the near future.

If no, how do I bypass the code signing error (certs and all)?

If yes... nvm...

---

For mac, do I need a license to test and run apps on my personal Mac?

Thanks in advance for your help. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test on the simulator for free, if you register as an Apple developer and download the iPhone SDK. To do so, go here: http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/

You will not be able to test on a real device, but from your question, it looks like this is not an issue. Also, by registering as an Apple developer, you can download and use Xcode to write Mac applications as well.

If you do decide that you need to run the app on an iOS device (even your own) or publish to the App Store, you will have to sign up for the [iOS Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/), which is $99/year.

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing but the Xcode and the iPhone SDK are completely free. If you want to put your application on your phone or if you want to publish to the app store you will need to pay $100 for a license as compared to Android which is free.

Comment: Incorrect. To publish to the Android Market, you need to be registered developer, and there's a $25 registration fee.

Comment: oh really, shoot I haven't got that far yet. Still cheaper than apple

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a developer code sign cert to run apps on the emulator. When you build your app, if you choose to build for the emulator, XCode will sign the code with a self-signed certain, which the emulator will happily accept.

You need the developer cert only if you are going to deploy on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the device test limitation, you cannot download and try beta versions of the SDK unless you are a member of the paid program.  You can download and install the current release and play with it all you want